# filter Get-Service by username

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all the services that run under the **user system**, but just them (not from other users). I don't find a way to filter the result by the user name.

I tried many options, include `Get-WmiObject`.
Is there a command or a parameter like `-IncludeUserName` (Works with Get-Process) that makes it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property called StartName is the username
below will filter out StartName = LocalSystem

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.StartName -eq 'LocalSystem'}
```

Comment: No probs Asher, if you want to see all properties of Win32_Service, just do
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Property * | select -First 1 | Select-Object *